# Download part of ethereum blockchain

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, web3py

Is it possible to download the full version of the Ethereum blockchain for the last 30 days? I'm interested in accessing logs of all transactions during this period. If direct download isn't viable, are there alternative methods or tools for achieving this?

I want to know is it possible.

Comment: Yes, probably. You may want to check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to download the full version of the Ethereum blockchain for the last 30 days?

To download Ethereum blockchain, you need to run Ethereum node.

The most popular Ethereum node software, GoEthereum, has an option to prune old history by a block range. This is the closest you get for "last 30 days."

However GoEthereum installation size is still going to be counted in hundreds of gigabytes, because for the needed data to sync with Ethereum blockchain.

Alternatively you can try Google's Ethereum BigQuery tables. You need to sign in with Google Cloud and pay them something.